# scrollTop not working with 2 operators

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So basically I am just trying to change the CSS class of a specific element upon scrolling. This worked great when using this code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 270) {
             $('.homeLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.homeLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
    });
```

However, I want to remove the class upon scrolling further. So I tried using this code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 270 &&  < 300) {
             $('.homeLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.homeLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
});
```

When using the 2nd code, it just doesn't work at all. Meaning, nothing changes.

I know I am just being stupid and doing this wrong, but I am not sure how to fix it. I am pretty big noob when it comes to js. Any help would be very appreciated.

#### EDIT:

I have also tried this with no luck:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
         if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 270 && $(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
             $('.homeLink').addClass('selected');
         }
         else {
             $('.homeLink').removeClass('selected');
         }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the correct sintax:

```
if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 270 && $(window).scrollTop() < 300) {
```

Comment: Well, with just 1 scroll you might pass the 300 mark without never reaching 270-300, so it might be working fine. Check with  `console.log($(window).scrollTop())`

Comment: When I had it just check for >= 270 it did work just fine. It was not until I added the 2nd operator that it failed. 

Again, kind of newby here, what exactly should I be doing with `console.log($(window).scrollTop())` ?

Comment: well, if you want the scrollTop to be between 270 and 300, if you are at 260 and suddenly scroll to 310, it will never enter your if. You should do the console.log right before the if and check in the console its value

Comment: Dude you were totally right, I feel retarded lol. Thank you sir! Adjusted to be `if($(this).scrollTop()>= 270 && $(this).scrollTop() < 500){` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($(this).scrollTop()>= 270 && $(this).scrollTop() < 300){
```

Comment: As juvian try logging it into console to debug it use this code to check if it works:  
`$(window).bind('scroll', function() {  
if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 270 && $(this).scrollTop() < 300){  
console.log('hi');  
} else {  
console.log('bye');  
 }  
});`

Comment: By the way, if you don't know what a console is, try ctrl+shift+k in chrome.